# How can I graph or chart date related values ( each date having one value )

Tags: applications

*NEW QUESTION*

- **I wish to enter dates with corresponding values**, and have these values **charted in a line or block graph**. If the chart and values could be exported, that would be nice.

*UPDATE*

Since the original title containing the words graph and commodities did not seem to produce any results, I have now changed the question to a more general question. Original question was: *I am looking for a way to **edit and graph my own commodities** off line ?*

*USE ( to clarify the question )*

- I could use this to create a graph from manually entered stock exchange values, but also to follow up my weight, or hart beat values, or whatever chart whose values change daily.
- I know that you can use a spreadsheet to do this, but I am looking for a more specialised program.
- I am running Froyo 2.2.1 on a Samsung Galaxy S and Archos 101 pad ( *if this should make a difference* ).

*UPDATE AFTER INITIAL COMMENTS*

Left the original question here, so that any read could understand the initial comments.

*I am looking for a stocks program where I can add and edit my own daily/weekly stock figures.
I want some graph too.
I don't want nor seek a program which offers real time or on line updated stock quotes.
I have looked in the marked, but there are tens or hundreds of stocks programs, and I really don't want to try them all ( especially because most if not all of them emphasise how easy it is to have real time updated values ).*